# Asycnhronous Logging when using properietary logging library

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous, parallel-processing

My team is working on a large middleware application thats meant to access a database and expose a certain amount of data to another application that will be accessed very often in the form of a Web Service and as such will be sending a large amount of requests to our application.

Currently we are in the planning phase and we are thinking about how we are going to implement logging. We are tied to a "proprietary" (in the sense that we can't alter it) logging framework made by the organization we work at which does not, on its own, support asynchronicity. Our logging library allows us to log to both a database and to a trace file and we are required to log to both, several times for each user request.

The basic idea we had that we are going to create a singleton class that creates a single thread with a queue and whenever we want to log something we would simply send the message to the queue and the logging thread would handle this. This ensures that messages are written to the db and to the trace log in the same order that they were received. An issue that might crop up here as well is that we also want our web services be called asynchronously in order to maximize the responsiveness of our web service and they might then write messages to the queue out of order. But I'm merely brainstorming here and I'm not as experienced in parallelism so I'd like to know if the way I'm thinking makes sense and what would be the smartest thing to do in this case.

Comment: If only one thread is doing the logging, then why do you think it will write things out of order, it would still write logs in the order they are received.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is seeking opinion on software design.  It might be suitable on another Stack Exchange site.  Be sure to read the site's FAQ before posting and revise your question as appropriate